# SQL Server installation failure error - 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object'

Tags: sql-server, installation

I am trying to install a Named Instance of SQL Server 2017 in my computer. I selected Database Engine Services in the feature list before installation. The installation failed and I got the following not so informative error message.

**The following error has occurred:
Object reference not set to an instance of an object**

I am using Windows 10 OS. I am running the setup as an Administrator. When asked to choose the authentication for the instance I chose Mixed Authentication.

Can someone tell me how to get past this problem.

Comment: Read the sql server installation log file located at `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\114\Setup Bootstrap\Log\Summary.txt`, also I have had similar issue and it was a corrupted installation media. Try downloading the installation files again.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.

I use Win 10 1806. I run the reparation tool for .NET Framework, and it didn’t solve the problem.

In my case the installation file of MS SQL Server was corrupted.

Comment: What was the solution?

Comment: download new installation file and rerun the installation

Answer (score 0):

This is most probably due to not having .NET Framework 4.6 installed.
If it is already installed on your machine, you can try running the .NET Framework repair tool, found [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-sg/download/details.aspx?id=30135)

Comment: I see .NET Framework 4.6 installed. I am going to try repairing.